# What does $.attr means in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jquery and I have encountered something like this

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(event) {
   $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
   }, 500);
});
```

This is a smooth scroll jquery and I understand most of it.
But I don't know how to read the `$.attr(this, 'href')`.
From the website of Jquery, .attr should be used in the following format

```
$(selector).attr(attributeName)

$(selector).attr(attributeName, value)
```

The  `$.attr(this, 'href')` has no `$(selector)`.
I have read some stackoverflow post said that `$.attr(this, 'href')` equals to `$(this).attr('href')`

Can anyone please give me more explanation on `$.attr(this, 'href')`? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it refers to the clicked anchor element. It's just another overload on the `attr` function.

Comment: It's the same as `$(this).attr('foo')` except you pass the scope as an argument.

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan Thanks for your explaination